# tidyjson: Replace existing column values in dataframe with output of spread_values

Tags: r, json

I have a data frame that has a column with JSON values. I found the library "tidyjson" which helps to extract this JSON. However, it is always extracted into a new data frame.

I am looking for a way to replace the JSON in the original data frame with the result of tidyjson.

Code:

```
mydf <- df$response %>% as.tbl_json %>% gather_array %>%
  spread_values(text=jstring('text'))
```

Is there a way that "df$response" is replaced with the extracted json "text"-value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

```
df %>% as.tbl_json(json.column = 'response') %>% gather_array %>%
  spread_values(response=jstring('text'))
```